# How to access props inside a filter with an argument in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
let regSug = []
const {targetProperty} = this.props
const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${value}`, "i");
regSug = APIData.sort().filter((v) => v.targetProperty); //Cant reach targetProperty
```

App.js:

```
function App() {
  return <Module targetProperty={"name"} />;
}
```

So I want to access a const inside filter in a anonymous function.

Comment: It's really not clear exactly what you're asking, but you probably want to use `v[targetProperty]`. (You also don't need the `{...}` around a JSX attribute if it's just a string.)

Comment: Thanks guys. Should have used bracket notation